# Assembly line reader

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm new to StackOverflow and pretty new to programming as a whole. I've got an Assignment in Assembly and one of the things I'm trying to do is to make a function that can read the number of lines in a text. This is what I've done so far:
EDIT: I've added more code for context, **but the main focus in on "loop".**

```
.global printf
print_num :
push {r0-r3 , lr }
ldr r0 , =fmt
bl printf
pop {r0-r3 , lr }
bx lr


 .global main
    main:
    ldr r1 , =txt @Loads the text as a single string into r1
    bl read_str @ This branches to the function read_str , reads the txt and stores in the txt string
    ldr r1 , =search_string
    ldr r2 , =txt
    mov r3 , #1 @ r3 = line number
    mov r4 , r2 @ r4 = pos of start of curr line
    mov r6 , #1 @ r6 = total num of lines in file
    @ ( the file starts at line 1)
    mov r7 , #0 @ r7 = num of lines that match
    b loop 
     
    loop:
     
    ldrb r5, [r2], #1 @This copies the first ASCII Code Byte of the text into r5 then increments r2 by 1 byte
    cmp r5, #10 @This compares the ASCII code stored in r5 with ASCII code '10'
    addeq r6, #1 @If the ASCII code is equal to 10 this means there is a new line and thus we add 1 to the line counter
    addeq r3, #1 @When new line this will increment the line number to make sure when a match if found we know what line it is on
    beq loop
    bne newloop
     
    newloop:
    cmp r5, #0 @New compare to see if the ASCII code is '0' which would signify the end of the string (ASCIZ)
    beq end_str @if the code is 0 the string is over to should jump to end_str to print
    bne loop @if not equal to zero it should redo loop until it is 
     
    end_str:
    push {r1-r7, lr} @This is popping all the values to the stack
    ldr r0, =num_of_lines_str @This loads the message into r0
    mov r1, r6 @This loads r6 (number of lines) into r1 
    bl print_num
    pop {r1-r7, lr}
    mov r7 , #1
    svc #0
     
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    .data
    search_string: .asciz "blue"
    newline: .asciz "\n"
    num_of_lines_str: .asciz " total num of lines : "
    num_of_matches_str: .asciz "num of matches : "
    fmt: .asciz "%d\n"
    txt: .space 1000000 @ input text as a single string
    .end
```

I'm doing this whole thing on Codio and I'm not sure as to what version I'm running this on. Point is whenever I read the text from a txt file, I always get an output of 2, regardless of how many lines there are.

Comment: The code shown is not a complete minimal example that can be used to reproduce the behavior you describe.

Comment: There aren't enough details to answer this question.  For example, what does `r2` hold?  What does `r6` hold?  What does `r3` hold?  What happens after this code?  It is impossible to answer your question without having at least a [mcve], but ideally that and some more in-depth explanations of what it is you are doing.

Comment: Please tag the architecture as well.

Comment: @m0skit0: Fortunately ARM has several unique syntax features that make it easy to spot: `@` is the comment character, `ldr reg, =constant` pseudo-instruction is also fairly unique to ARM AFAIK, and push/pop multiple registers as `pop {r4, pc}` for example.  Also predicated instructions like `addeq` (add when the EQ condition is true, else NOP).  So yes, people should tag the architecture, but here it's almost totally safe to make the assumption and add the tag yourself, as I've done.  Not like code that could be MIPS or RISC-V, or one of a few microcontrollers or whatever.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sure, but I have to click on the question to check that :)